# paramMap property logging undefined to console

Tags: angular

I have some routes setup in my photo gallery app:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/gallery', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id', component: ImageFullViewComponent},
  ]},
```

When the user clicks on an image from the gallery list component here:

```
<ul class="container">
        <li class="item-list-container"><app-image-item
        class="image-item"
        *ngFor="let imageEl of images"
        [image]="imageEl"
        (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"
        ></app-image-item>
        </li>
    </ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My onImageSelect method is executed from within the gallery list component:

```
  onImageSelect(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/gallery', id])
    console.log(id);
  }
```

The image should then display on a different component ('image-full-view' component):

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image-full-view" [src]="selectedImage.imagePath" alt="Man Praying">
    <p>{{ selectedImage.name }}</p>
</div>
```

The selectedImage is retrieved from the 'image-full-view' component here:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap['id'];

    console.log(id);
    this.selectedImage = this.galleryService.getImage(id);
    console.log(this.selectedImage);
  }
```

This doesn't work and I keep getting redirected back to the gallery component. I have discovered that when logging the id variable to the console, it is returning "undefined". It should be returning the id which is retrieved from the url path. also an error message appears saying "Cannot read property 'imagePath' of undefined".

Comment: `this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
            const id = params.get( 'id' );
            this.id = +id;
          });`

Comment: I have tried implementing your code but I am still getting undefined logged to the console

Comment: check out my answer and live demo in StackBlitz link provided there too.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo** in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfzvpq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgallery%2Fgallery.component.html)

As you can not get parmMap from details component i will use observable approach. Because of this approach gives us future image url change and update according to it. You can give your data of image-url. I am here only giving getting paramMap data overview with my data. approach is same in your case too.

**gallery.component.ts**

```
export class GalleryComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router ) { }
  fullView(index: number){
    this.router.navigate(['/gallery' , index])
  }
}
```

**gallery.componenet.html**

```
<div class="container m-1 p-1">
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click) ="fullView(1)"> One </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click) ="fullView(2)"> Two </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click) ="fullView(3)"> Three </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click) ="fullView(4)"> Four </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click) ="fullView(5)"> Five </button>
</div>
<br>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**image-fullview.component.html**

```
<div class="container m-1" *ngIf="id">
  <span class="alert alert-primary m-1" > Your selected ID is : {{id}} </span>
</div>
```

**image-fullview.component.ts**

```
export class ImageFullViewComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe( (id: ParamMap) =>{
      this.id = +id.get('id');
    })
  }
}
```

In above image-fullview we are subscribing to paramMap and then whenever from gallery component image clicked that it displayed here in this image-fullview component.